# Stream Pipewire audio to web browser with low-latency and high quality

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, pipewire

On my Linux host where audio is managed by Pipewire, I'm playing audio files (FLAC, MP3, OGG) with various music players (e.g. VLC, mpv, mpd) which all output to the default audio device.

Besides playing the music on the audio device, I also want to publish the music to a web browser within the local network (providing high bandwidth and low latency).
The published web stream should not be more than 1-2 seconds behind than the sound playing on audio device, but does not be as perfect as Snapcast (which provides no real web client afaik).

Is it possible to extend Pipewire so it mirrors all audio output to a HTTP stream? Or is there some external media server supporting the use case?
The stream should be:

- low latency (ideally 1-2s)
- high quality (should support FLAC)
- unidirectional (only server to few clients)

Comment: "is there some external media server supporting the use case ?" You had mentioned *mpd* earlyer. What's wrong with it ?

Comment: And regarding VLC, what about https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-stream-video-from-vlc ?

Comment: @MC68020 I'd like to be able to switch between player backends (mpv, mpd, vlc, ...) and decouple audio streaming. With pipewire and gstreamer this is in theory possible but badly documented.

Comment: It's definitely possible with low-latency streaming software like OBS->OvenPlayer. I don't know if it's possible with Pipewire itself, sorry.